# ブラウザのコンソールログで指定メッセージが表示されたら、という条件分岐をしたい

Tags: javascript, api

**現状**
あるAPIを実行すると、ブラウザのコンソールログに指定メッセージが表示されます

コンソールログ表示例

> hoge

---

**やりたいこと**
ブラウザのコンソールログに指定メッセージが表示されたら、という条件分岐をしたいです

疑似コード

```
if(コンソールログにhogeと表示されていたら)
{
}
```

---

**試したこと**
APIからのレスポンスオブジェクト構造を確認してみましたが、どの箇所でブラウザのコンソールログに指定メッセージを表示させているのか分かりませんでした

Answer (score 1, accepted):

呼ばれ方次第ですけど、コンソールログといっているのが `console.log("hoge");` で呼ばれてるんならこっそり console.log にモンキーパッチするのでどうですか。

```
var orig = console.log;
console.log = function () {
    orig.apply(console, arguments);

    if (arguments[0].match(/hoge/)) {
        alert("HOGE!");
    }
}

// 確認したいコード
console.log("foobar");  // 普通のconsole.logのフリをする
console.log("hoge");    // HOGE!
```

Comment: 試してみたのですが、コンソールログに「Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: arguments[0].match is not a function」と表示されました。返ってきているのはpromiseオブジェクトで何か特別な処理が必要なのでしょうか？

Comment: 問題の箇所がconsole.logにPromiseオブジェクトを渡しているのでは。

Comment: 文字列型オブジェクトだけに限定するとか。`if (typeof arguments[0] == 'string' && arguments[0].match(/hoge/)) { ...`

Comment: 試してみたら、期待した通り動作するようになりました